# How to make Yii2's checkbox label not clickable?

Tags: checkbox, yii2

I need to disable the possiblity to check the checkbox by clicking on the label. User should be able to check the checkbox only on clicking the box itself. I need to assign different action to click on label. How should I do that?

This is my code atm:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'accept')->checkbox(['template' => '{input}{beginLabel}{labelTitle}{endLabel}']);
```

That is something that supposed to work in Yii 1.x, but is not working in Yii2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure , but you can try this : BY giving padding , or custom label .

```
<!-- CHECKBOX BUTTON DEFAULT LABEL -->
<?= $form->field($model, 'population')->checkbox(); ?>
<!-- CHECKBOX BUTTON WITHOUT LABEL -->
<?= $form->field($model, 'population')->checkbox(array('label'=>'')); ?>
<!-- CHECKBOX BUTTON WITH CUSTOM LABEL -->
<?= $form->field($model, 'population')  ->checkbox(array('label'=>''))
                                        ->label('Gender'); ?>
<!-- CHECKBOX BUTTON WITH LABEL OPTIONS, DISABLED AND STYLE PROPERTIES -->
<?= $form->field($model, 'population')->checkbox(array(
                                'label'=>'',
                                'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'padding:5px;'),
                                'disabled'=>true                                
                                ))
                                ->label('Gender'); ?>
```

Id it is not working then , Define a HTML label manual

```
<label>Gender</label>
```

and

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'population')->checkbox(array('label'=>'')); ?>
```

Comment: Nope, no success. The label would still be wrapped around the input, making the label clickable. One option would be using BaseHTML's `activeCheckbox()` and `label()`, but in that case no error message will be showed and validation would not work.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, this one's working and also the error dispalying is working. But any idea how to align manually defined label correctly? This way the label is printed before or after the input according to where you put it. If it's after input, then error message will push it even more down, making the output not very elegant.

Comment: try to use css , margin and padding. it will work , don't forget to upvote and  accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

field($model, 'status')->checkbox(array('label'=>'Show Other Income on Report','checked'=>true))
                                        ; ?>